# Metal Shading Language - use Struct to get buffer value

Tags: swift, macos, kernel, metal

How can I use `struct` to get the buffer value? For example:

```
struct mouseInput
{
float x;
float y;
};

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant float &time [[buffer(0)]],
                    constant mouseInput.x &mouseX [[buffer(1)]],///<--mouseX from swift
                    constant mouseInput.y &mouseY [[buffer(2)]],///<--mouseY from swift
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
...
}
```

Then I can access `mouseInput.x` and so anywhere in `Metal`. The closest is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135788/creating-globally-accessible-constant-buffer-in-metal-shading-language) however I am not sure how to translate that into my use.

Answer (score 2):

Using separate buffers for the two components of the mouse position seems silly and wasteful to me.

Create a single buffer that contains both. Then write your compute function with a signature like:

```
struct mouseInput
{
float x;
float y;
};

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant float &time [[buffer(0)]],
                    constant mouseInput &mouse [[buffer(1)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
...
}
```

In fact, depending on the rest of your app, it probably makes sense to combine the time with the mouse position:

```
struct params
{
    float time;
    float2 mouse;
};

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant params &params [[buffer(0)]],
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
...
// use params.time to get the time value.
// Use params.mouse.x and params.mouse.y to get the mouse position.
}
```